# Test Angular Component Throws Error Fails With TypeError

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, jasmine

I have defined a `CustomError` as

```
export class CustomError extends Error {
    constructor(message?: string) {
        super(message);
        Object.setPrototypeOf(this, CustomError.prototype);
    }
}
```

and I want to throw `CustomError` from an angular component, e.g.,

```
@Component({
    moduleId: 'module.id',
    templateUrl: 'my.component.html'
})
export class MyComponent {
    someMethod(): void {
        throw new CustomError();
    }
}
```

Now I want to test that `CustomError` is thrown, so I write the following test

```
describe('MyComponent', () => {

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [MyComponent]
        }).compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
    }));

    it('throws CustomError', () => {
        expect(component.someMethod).toThrowError(CustomError);
    });
});
```

This test passes as expected. However, if I now introduce `someProperty` into `MyComponent`, i.e.,

```
@Component({
    moduleId: 'module.id',
    templateUrl: 'my.component.html'
})
export class MyComponent {
    someProperty: string  = "Why does this break it?";

    someMethod(): void {
        console.log(this.someProperty);  // This breaks it, why?
        throw new CustomError();
    }
}
```

and attempt to use that property in the function I'm testing (in this case writing to the console), my test fails because a `TypeError` is thrown - stack trace below:

```
Expected function to throw AuthError, but it threw TypeError.
        at Object.<anonymous> (webpack:///src/app/auth/login/login.component.spec.ts:46:32 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:68955:33) [ProxyZone]
        at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:79:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:65355:39) [ProxyZone]
        at Object.<anonymous> (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js:104:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:65071:34) [ProxyZone]
        at webpack:///~/@angular/core/@angular/core/testing.es5.js:96:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:20767:17 [ProxyZone]
        at AsyncTestZoneSpec.onInvoke (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/async-test.js:49:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:64666:39) [ProxyZone]
        at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:76:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:65352:39) [ProxyZone]
        at AsyncTestZoneSpec._finishCallback (webpack:///~/@angular/core/@angular/core/testing.es5.js:91:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:20762:25) [<root>]
        at webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/async-test.js:38:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:64655:31 [<root>]
        at timer (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1732:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:67191:29) [<root>]
```

Why does this throw a `TypeError` and break my test?

Comment: shouldn't it be `console.log(this.someProperty)`?

Comment: @adiga yes, that was a typo. The test still fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You lost context `this`.

```
getJasmineRequireObj().toThrowError = function(j$) {
  function toThrowError () {
    return {
      compare: function(actual) {
        var threw = false,
          pass = {pass: true},
          fail = {pass: false},
          thrown;

        if (typeof actual != 'function') {
          throw new Error('Actual is not a Function');
        }

        var errorMatcher = getMatcher.apply(null, arguments);

        try {
          actual(); // call function reference component.someMethod
```

I would write

```
expect(component.someMethod.bind(component)).toThrowError(CustomError);
```